# How to make star rating work with keyboard focus

Tags: jquery

I am working on a five star rating and i have gotten to to work on click as well as on hover however, i cannot get it to work using the tab key on the keyboArd. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as i have also tried focus() but it doesn't work.

On mouseover, the star which the cursor is on, becomes active and same applies to all previous stars. so for instance, if the cursor hovered over the third star, the third star, second star and first star would be hightlighted. I would like to achieve the same thing using keyboard

```
<div> 
    <div>
        <div class="left">
            <p><strong>Rate this article</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="left hide star-rating-message">
            <p>Thank you for your rating!</p>
        </div>      
        <div class="left fivestar">
            <div class="left hide average-rating-message">
                <p>Average rating</p>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="fivestar-btn-empty"><span class="hide">a</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fivestar-btn-empty"><span class="hide">b</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" class="fivestar-btn-empty"><span class="hide">c</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fivestar-btn-empty"><span class="hide">d</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fivestar-btn-empty"><span class="hide">e</span></a></li>
            </ul>

       </div>   
       <div class="clearboth fivestar-comment">
           <div class="left hide padding8b comment-rating-message">
               <p>Thank you for your feedback!</p>
           </div>           
       </div>
    </div>  
</div>



//on hover
$(this).hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().children('a').addClass('fivestar-btn-filled').removeClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    $(this).children('a').addClass('fivestar-btn-filled').removeClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    $(this).nextAll().children('a').removeClass('fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('fivestar-btn-empty');

},function() {
    $(this).parent().children().children('a').removeClass('fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('fivestar-btn-empty');}
});
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net so we can see how it should render?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2**: Combined your code (hover) with mine (focus); full code [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/9EwUZ/)

```
var lock = false; // Prevents the hover from working when an element has focus

// Focus gain
$("a").focus(function() {
    lock = true;
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('a')
        .addClass('fivestar-btn-filled').removeClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    $(this).addClass('fivestar-btn-filled').removeClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    $(this).parent().nextAll().children('a').removeClass('fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
});
// Focus lost
$("a").blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('a')
        .removeClass('fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    $(this)
        .removeClass('fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('fivestar-btn-empty');
    lock = false;
});
```

On your code, prevent the hover callbacks from running, adding this in the beggining of both (enter and exit):

```
if ( lock )
    return;
```

Comment: it works to an extent but a bit buggy across browsers especially chrome.

Comment: What are the problems you're having now? Sure, to have the focus and hover work together might be a bit tricky, but I didn't experience any bugs with the code above. What version of jQuery are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want CSS selector:focus and then set css styles so the user knows they are on it.

Comment: that would not solve the problem cus using css would only show one star at a time. if the focus was on the third star, the third star and previous two stars should become active